# Redraw outside drawRect function

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a function that draws a rectangle. If called within drawRect image is drawn perfectly. If I call the function directly it doesn't draw the rect. When I searched I found that we need to `setNeedsDisplay` to Yes. But still it doesn't work.

Comment: setNeedsDisplay causes drawRect to be called. 

Can you leave your rectangle drawing function in drawRect and not call it directly?

Comment: In NSView instances, content can only be drawn within the `drawRect` method, and drawing outside of that method is unfortunately not supported. However, the `drawRect` method can read data from other objects and use it to determine what to draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such questions the best method is to use a boolean flag. Then call the function inside `drawRect:` only when the flag is set.

Now when you need the image to be drawn set the flag value to true and then call the `[view setNeedsDisplay:YES];`

If need be change the flag to false within the if statement once the task has been done.

Answer (score 2):

You can only draw to your window when the system invokes your `drawRect:` method.  You should not call it directly.  The system will activate the graphics context before calling `drawRect:` and perform various housekeeping functions before and after its invocation.

To explicitly request the entire window to be redrawn, you call:

```
[view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

This will cause your `drawRect:` method to be called in the next event loop.

The documentation covers all this in detail:

- [Cocoa Drawing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/DrawingEnviron/DrawingEnviron.html)